# Why `uname -a` invoke exit1 for sslocal?

Tags: bash, exit

The shadowsocks client was running in my pc.

```
uname -a
Linux MiWiFi 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo sh -c '/usr/bin/nohup   /usr/local/bin/sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks_racks.json  > /var/log/ss.log 2>&1'
```

Why command `uname -a` invoke Exit1 for sslocal here?
What does `Exit 1 sudo sh -c '/usr/bin/nohup   /usr/local/bin/sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks_racks.json  > /var/log/ss.log 2>&1'`
 mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why command `uname -a` invoke Exit1 for sslocal here?

You've completely misinterpreted the output. Before `uname` ran, a background command running as job 1 exited with a status code of 1. The shell couldn't tell you until a command was run, and now you have been told.